# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder on Docker container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I have a Spring Boot Backend which runs well on my local machine on IntelliJ.

But when I try to run it on the Docker Container I get this error

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emailSenderService' defined in URL [jar:file:/app/Backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/hdmstuttgart/mi/backend/service/EmailSenderService.class]: Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'mjmlSecrets.appId' in value "${mjmlSecrets.appId}"
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
openbarber-backend-1   |        ... 32 common frames omitted
openbarber-backend-1   | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'mjmlSecrets.appId' in value "${mjmlSecrets.appId}"
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:191)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:936)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1332)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
openbarber-backend-1   |        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
openbarber-backend-1   |        ... 41 common frames omitted
openbarber-backend-1 exited with code 1
```

It seems that it cannot resolve the placeholder in this case some credentials.

In the `application.yml` the credentials are configured like this

```
mailCredentials:
  username: ${MAIL_USERNAME}
  password: ${MAIL_PASSWORD}

mjmlSecrets:
  appId: ${MJML_APP_ID}
  appKey: ${MJML_APP_KEY}
```

the credentials are in a `.env` file

```
MAIL_USERNAME=yourMailUsername
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourMailPassword
MJML_APP_ID=yourMjmlAppId
MJML_APP_KEY=yourMjmlAppKey
```

And in the docker-compose file I set the environment variables like this as well

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  frontend:
    hostname: localhost
    build: ./Frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  backend:
    build: ./Backend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/openbarber
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=admin
      - MJML_APP_ID=...
      - MJML_APP_KEY=...
      - MAIL_USERNAME=...
      - MAIL_PASSWORD=...
    env_file:
      - ./Backend/src/main/resources/.env
```

Is the configuration correct?
I also tried a `mvn clean install`

Comment: By [Spring Boot's rules](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables) you should be able to set environment variables like `MJMLSECRETS_APPID` without specifically mentioning the properties in `application.yml`.  (Consider writing a `@ConfigurationProperties` class to encapsulate these, if you don't have one already.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/) about setting environment variables.

> The `.env` file is the default method for setting environment variables
> in your containers. **The `.env` file should be placed at the root of the
> project directory next to your `compose.yaml` file.**

It is the best way.

But if you want to declare it in another place you have to change location that is not in `src/...`.

More details and example you could find in reference that I gave to documentation.

Comment: Even though I moved the `.env` to the root folder, it still cannot resolve the placeholder

Comment: how do you pass `- MJML_APP_ID=...` ?